# CSS animation not smooth still i have Graphics Card and hardware acceleration on in Chrome

Tags: html, css, animation

Here is a demo CSS animation, that creating when i click on animate text button through the changing css classes.

But it is not smoothly changing...

**NOTE:** when i do not add `text-shadow` property then it is animating smooth, But when i add `text-shadow` property then it's lag / not smooth.

**NOTE:** and YES it is smoothly working on Firefox browser.

Why ?

although i have on hardware acceleration on in Chrome browser and i have AMD latest processer and NVIDIA latest graphics card.

What i should to do now ?

WHOLE CODE:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".animate").click(function(){
    $(".r1").addClass("r2");
        $(".r16").addClass("r15");
          $(".r15").removeClass("r16");
    $(".r2").removeClass("r1");
  });
});
```

```css
.r1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
perspective: 1000;
}

.r2 {

  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.7s;
color: #fff;
width: 400px;  height: 100px; 
  text-align: center;
      margin-left: 310px;
    font-size: 33px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
perspective: 1000;
  animation-timing-function: linear;

}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {  width: 400px;
  height: 300px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 60px; font-size: 50px;}

  100% { width: 400px;  height: 100px;   font-size: 33px; margin-left: 310px;}
}


.r15 {
  animation-name: r15;
  animation-duration: 0.7s;
  color: #fff;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
perspective: 1000;
  animation-timing-function: linear;

}


@keyframes r15 {
  0%   {  filter: brightness(401%); hue-rotate(88deg);     text-shadow: 0 0 0px #fff, 0 0 0px #fff, 0 0 0px #e60073, 0 0 0px #e60073, 0 0 0px #e60073, 0 0 0px #e60073, 0 0 0px #e60073; invert(75%); blur(0px);  
color: black;
transform: scale(1, 1);}

  40%   {  filter: brightness(401%) hue-rotate(88deg); text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #e60073, 0 0 40px #e60073, 0 0 50px #e60073, 0 0 60px #e60073, 0 0 70px #e60073; invert(75%) blur(4px);  
color: black;
transform: scale(0.4, 0.8);}
  
  100% { filter: brightness(401%); hue-rotate(88deg);     text-shadow: 0 0 0px #fff, 0 0 0px #fff, 0 0 0px #e60073, 0 0 0px #e60073, 0 0 0px #e60073, 0 0 0px #e60073, 0 0 0px #e60073; invert(75%); blur(0px);  
color: black;
transform: scale(1, 1);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="animate">Animate Text</button>

<div class="r1"><div class="r16">SOME Text i want to animate it with text shadow effect but it lag</div> </div>
```

Comment: In my FF and Chrome it works in the same way. Btw, your effect is very complicated but not impressive.